# xConnect MergeContacts operation does not copy the facet data to Target Contact

Tags: xconnect, contact-facets

Request your support.

I have two contacts with same email id and different source identifier. I want to perform `mergeContacts()` operation on these two contacts. I am using standard xConnect API.

```
client.MergeContacts(SourceContact, TargetContact);
```

I see merge operation is getting successful but I don't see facet data is copied from `SourceContact` to `TargetContact`.

Source & Target contact has one marketing preference each. I am expecting two marketing preferences on Target contact once merge get succeeded.

Thanks
Hari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected behavior.

When you call `client.MergeContacts` it will copy facets from Source contact to Target Contact, but it will not merge any facets.

`ExmKeyBehaviorCache` facet contains a list of `MarketingPreference` objects. When you merge, it will just copy the whole `ExmKeyBehaviorCache` facet. It will not merge lists of marketing preferences from `ExmKeyBehaviorCache` source contact facet with `ExmKeyBehaviorCache` target contact facet.

---

**EDIT**

Here is the information from Sitecore documentation ( https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-platform/merge-contacts.html ):

> All value facets are copied from the source contact to the target contact except when the facet already exists on the target contact. For example, if the target contact already has PersonalInformation facet, it will not be overridden by the source contact’s PersonalInformation facet.
>
> **Note**
>
> Experience Optimization’s TestCombinations facet behaves differently - if an anonymous contact was exposed to a test combination and then identifies themselves partway through the session, the known contact’s test combinations facet will be overwritten.
>
> Calculated facet merge handlers are executed.

And another part:

> **Custom merge handlers**
>
> You must create a calculated facet merge handler for calculated facets, as they may required custom merge logic. Value facets are merged automatically. However, you can create a merge handler for a value facet if that facet requires custom merge logic.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-platform/create-a-facet-merge-handler.html

Comment: Thanks Marek for your answer. I am surprised that its expected behaviour.  If Target contact has ExmKeyBehaviorCache facet, Would it still copy the ExmKeyBehaviorCache from Source contact? or Would it only copy if Target contact does not have ExmKeyBehaviorCache facet?

Comment: @HariWaghamare see updated answer